# Неверный request url в swagger при запросе через ocelot

Tags: c#, swagger

При запросах через страницу swagger в gateway, в запрос подставляется порт gateway, а не приложения за ним, возникает ошибка 404.

При запросах в swagger через прямой адресс к приложению (127.0.0.1:5100), все запросы работают.

Как изменить url запроса через gateway?

**Запрос через ocelot:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**ocelot.json:**

```
    "Routes": [
        {
          "DownstreamScheme": "http",
          "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
            {
              "Host": "127.0.0.1",
              "Port": 5100
            }
          ],
          "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/{url}",
          "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/modules/{url}",
          "UpstreamHttpMethod": [
            "GET",
            "POST",
            "PUT",
            "DELETE"
          ],
          "ReRouteIsCaseSensitive": false,
          "Priority": 0
        }
    ],
 "SwaggerEndPoints": [
        {
            "Key": "Modules",
            "VersionPlaceholder": null,
            "KeyToPath": "Modules",
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Name": "Modules API",
                    "Version": "v1",
                    "Url": "http://127.0.0.1:5100/v1/swagger.json",
                    "Service": null
                }
            ],
            "HostOverride": null,
            "TransformByOcelotConfig": false
        }
]
```

**Конфигурация swagger за gateway:**

```
        private void AddSwagger(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c => c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Modules", Version = "V1" }));
            services.ConfigureSwaggerGen(options => { options.CustomSchemaIds(x => x.FullName); });
        }

        private void ConfigureSwagger(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app
                .UseSwagger()
                .UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/swagger.json", "Modules API"));
        }
```

**Конфигурация swagger в gateway:**

```
        services.AddSwaggerForOcelot(Configuration,o => { o.GenerateDocsForGatewayItSelf = true; });
        services.AddControllers();

        app.UseSwaggerForOcelotUI(opt =>
        {
           opt.DownstreamSwaggerHeaders = new[]
           {
              new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Accept", "application/json")
           };
        })
        .UseOcelot().Wait();
```

Comment: У вас в одном случает порт 5000, во втором случае 5100.

Comment: @aepot ocelot слушает 5000 и перенаправляет запрос на 5100